# ProPublica's COMPAS Data | Feature Descriptions

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

ProPublica kindly provided the COMPAS Recidivism data in the github: https://github.com/propublica/compas-analysis/blob/master/compas-scores-two-years-violent.csv

Most of the features are clear from their name. But there are few variables like e.g., start , end, event etc..etc. which are not clear. What do these variables actually mean? Does anybody have any idea? Is there any place that I can find a description of the variables?

I all have searched the documents:
https://www.propublica.org/article/how-we-analyzed-the-compas-recidivism-algorithm
and
http://www.northpointeinc.com/files/technical_documents/FieldGuide2_081412.pdf

None of them contain any description of those 3 variables ( start, end, event).

I have contacted many researchers all are saying ProPublica doesn't provide an official codebook for the data..which makes it really difficult to use it confidently.

The owner of the dataset doesn't bother to answer.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Nowhere I find the description of variables.